# Termination of CAT7A cable with CAT8 Keystone RJ45 connectors

Tags: networking, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

I'm reconstructing our home and I'm thinking to upgrade the network. A part from the computer network I want to run some smart home applications and connect sensors over the network wires with PoE. As the walls are torn, now I have the chance to add new network cable for the years to come.
I'm thinking to install CAT7A cable as it has bigger broadband and offers future possibilities to for higher speeds with upgrade of the other network components.

I know that the specifications say that CAT7 and CAT7A cables should be terminated with GG45 or Tera connectors for best performance, but now I read [here](https://infinity-cable-products.com/blogs/news/cat7-cat7a-rj45-and-keystone-jack-compatibility) and [here](https://www.lanshack.com/Cat-8-Shielded-Toolless-Keystone-Jack-40G-Fits-Cat7A-Cat8-Cable-P8305.aspx) that CAT8 Keystone RJ45 connectors can also be used for termination of CAT7 cables as well. Is this true or is this some kind of marketing trick? Has someone already used Keystone 8 RJ45 connectors to terminate CAT7A cable?

If it is possible to do this I will hire a company with experience in the field to do the cabling.

TIA,
Jovan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10GBASE-T is the latest IEEE 802.3 (Ethernet) standard to use twisted pair copper, and it uses Cat 6a. It's unclear what grade of twisted pair copper any future Ethernet technology might use, or even if there will ever be another flavor of Ethernet that uses twisted pair at all. So it's a fool's errand to try to future proof against that.

The ISO/IEC jumped the gun by inventing new cable categories that neither the EIA/TIA nor the IEEE were ready to use. Cat 7 and better are currently solutions in search of problems.

Wire your house for Cat 6a, and be sure to use one of those fancy expensive Fluke testers to certify that each drop fully meets Cat 6a requirements, and call it done. Consider installing it in conduits with extra room for future cables, and leave pulling line in the conduits to make a future pulling job easier. Maybe make sure your conduits are suitable for putting fiber optic cables through (mind your bend radiuses). Because who knows, you might end up pulling single-mode fiber when you want 100G.

Comment: Totally agree. 6a does 10 Gb/s over 100 meters and 25 Gb/s over 30 meters. That is good enough for any home for the next 10 years. By that time we either go completely wireless or use the then current cabling (copper or fiber). You can do CAT7 with CAT6a rated RJ45 wall-outlets if you want, but it doesn't make any difference for your network components. It just comes down to price. Whatever you do: Stay away from CCA (Copper Clad Aluminum) cables. They are cheaper than copper, but they degrade badly over time. (Will not do 10 Gb/s after 7-8 years. Degradation is even worse in humid climate.)

Comment: @Tonny, I have never heard of an accelerated time-dependent degredation regarding CCA.  **7/8 years?**  Do you have a source for it where I can read up on it?  CCA provides a theoretically inferior _signal medium_ at higher frequencies but it's minimal and dependent upon how thick the cladding is.  But there has never been any concern I've heard from anyone regarding longevity.

Comment: @tgm1024--Monicawasmistreated Personal experience in multiple buildings where CCA was installed. Also experience from colleagues at other locations all over Europe. The boundary layer between the copper and aluminum is subject to chemical interaction between the metals (acerbated by moisture) that changes the electrical properties. Really cheap CCA will start to noticably degrade after 7/8 years. Better quality cable will last maybe 10 to 12 years. I had Cat 6 CCA dropping from 10 Gigabit to 1 Gb after 8 years on a 20 meter run. And a year later it was down to 100 Mb/s.